# How do i know if my Cocoapods is installed by gem or by brew(Homebrew)?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

How do i know if my Cocoapods is installed by gem or by brew(Homebrew) ?

In order for me to avoid having 2 versions of cocoapods and update it properly. I'll need to know which tool I installed it with so I can upgrade it on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Gem :

   gem list --local | grep cocoapods
2. Homebrew :

   brew list | grep cocoapods